# Google chrome does not appear in installed list in app center

Tags: updates, google-chrome

Google chrome is not in the install list in app center.  Does it get updated anyway? If it does not, how to fix this?

Comment: You mean Chromium?

Comment: I answered your question, but rereading it, I feel that I may have misunderstood it. Could you elaborate on what you've done, and what exactly it is that diverts from the expected behavior

Comment: Dear user3801839, Thank you for the answer. Just to elaborate, I installed Google Chrome on Elementary OS by downloading a deb file and running dpkg. As I mentioned above it did not appear in the AppCenter, although many other apps that I installed the same way did appear in the AppCenter and tend to get timely updates. Couple days ago, I checked the version of the Chrome and it was 71.0... The latest version on google site was 72. So I put together a short script that downloads the latest deb file and installs it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has to be [downloaded](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and installed either with dpkg or a graphical front end, such as [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/)

After installing, you can safely delete the .Deb package, as the application will appear under the 'updates' tab in your AppCenter, and can be removed from there.

Such an operation is called sideloading, and while generally discouraged, it is also at time necessary.

**UPDATE:**
On my computers, chrome doesn't show up in the AppCenter either, after installing it through the above stated methods. They do however, both, run the current version of it, so yes, **it does get updates**

Comment: Dear user3801839,  Thank you for the answer.  Just to elaborate,  I installed Google Chrome on Elementary OS by downloading a deb file and running dpkg.  As I mentioned above it did not appear in the AppCenter, although many other apps that I installed the same way did appear in the AppCenter and tend to get timely updates.  Couple days ago, I checked the version of the Chrome and it was 71.0...  The latest version on google site was 72.  So I put together a short script that downloads the latest deb file and installs it.